# How to escape a new line character in command promp

Tags: batch-file

Simple question:

echo Current time: &time /t &date /t

Returns 
time
date

I want - time date

Comment: `%time% %date%` should provide the info you appear to want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `%time%` and `%date%` for the same. `

```
echo %time% %date%
```

If you want to get the current time in `HH:MM` format, then try below

```
echo %time:~0,5% %date%
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean, `Echo %TIME:~0,5% %DATE%`?

Comment: @Compo Opps... thanks for the correction! Updated the same.